# Count unique words in a long long string

Tags: c, string, algorithm

Suppose I have an entire one(or two) book in memory and I want to count the number of unique words in it, how do I count it? My naive approach for small string was to:

```
create a simple hash, place it in array of fixed size, increment array element
All words for which hash array has 1 in it, are unique.
```

I want a better approach for my really really long string. I am coding in C. One approach I thought would be to using worker threads that work in blocks and combine results. Is there a better algorithm?

Comment: use Hadoop! https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount

Comment: Can you show your code for what you have so far? You'll be more likely to get an answer if you ask a specific question rather than something generic and openended?

Comment: Multiple threads will only help if you have multiple processors available and significantly complicate the algorithm. No matter how you break it down though, some piece of code needs to go over every word. Your simple, straight forward approach seems reasonable but I wouldn't use a fixed size array as you may run out of space.

Comment: Pretty sure that this is the problem that the [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) was invented to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user3386109 already mentioned a Trie would be the optimal solution. The basic idea is to create a Tree of characters. For example:

```
                             a
                            / \
                           /   \
                          b     c
                         /     / \
                        /     /   \
                       d     a     b
```

Would contain the words "a", "ab", "abd", "ac", "aca" and "acb". Simply extend that approach to a Treemap mapping each word to it's corresponding count and the whole lookup becomes linear and can be done parralelly to running through the word:

```
trie lookup
trienode node = lookup.root

for char c in input:
    if c == ' ':
        //end of word, increment count
        node.count += 1

        //start with root again
        node = lookup.root
    else:
        //go to matching node in the trie
        if !node.hasChild(c)
            node.insertChild(c)

        node = node.childForChar(c)

if node != lookup.root
     //increment count for last word, if the last char wasn't a space
    node.count += 1
```

The trie constructed by this method now just needs to be analysed. This can easily be done by simply filtering all nodes with a larger count than 0 and listing the paths of these nodes and their respective count.

You may want to add filtering for punctuation-characters, numbers, etc. . But if the lookup for childnodes is designed properly, this approach can scan the whole text in `O(n)`, even with a `HashTree` for the lookup-tables for children, the lookup could still be performed in logarithmic time, resulting in `O(n log n)`, with `n` being the length of the input-text (characters in the input-text).

Thanks to @PaulHankin for doing a benchmark. The result is basically: depending on how much we can restrict the input-alphabet, a `Trie` works better than a `HashTable` (as proposed by @PaulHankin), or performs worse. If the input is restricted to lowercase-letters, a trie performs 2.6x better than `HashTable`, if we allow all 256 ASCII-characters and use an array as lookup-table, the performance degrades to 1.3x the performance of a `HashTable`. Using a `HashMap` as looup-table for childnodes further degrades the performance of the `Trie` to 2x the runtime an algorithm utilizing a `HashTable`. So after all the speed of this algorithm really depends upon how much you are willing to restrict the size of the input-alphabet.

Comment: always gotta love those downvotes without giving a reason... . Anyways, any mistakes I made?

Comment: @user3386109 sry, meant `O(n)`. And the complexity of `O(n * m)` with `n` as word-count and `m` as average-wordlength would be equivalent to `O(c)` with `c` being the number of characters in the input-text.

Comment: Yup, you are correct. I was thinking in terms of word count, for comparison to other data structures that act on words instead of characters.

Comment: A trie is very likely to perform much worse than a hash table and use many times more memory. While there's some re-use of nodes as prefixes are shared, the cost of the many pointers you need in each node (and/or hash tables) is extremely difficult to overcome and will result in horrible memory locality.

Comment: @PaulHankin I doubt that. A good hash-function on it's own will already consume more runtime than the entire lookup in a trie, assuming the child-lookup is implemented properly. The memory-efficiency is horrible, as I already said, though. But since OP was talking about two books or sth like that, the memory-efficiency of the trie won't be that bad and compared to the amount of data that will be analysed a trie won't carry that much weight. And the hash-table itself will quite likely experience a lot of collisions resulting in a drain of performance aswell.

Comment: @Paul I did some benchmarks. If you assume you only have lower-case a-z, and so use a fixed array of 26 pointers in each trie node, I got the trie to be 2.5x faster than a hash table. With 256 pointers in each trie node it's 1.3x slower than a hash table. If you use a map in each trie node, it's 2x slower than a hash table. So I was wrong about the performance, and a trie is definitely a reasonable choice of datastructure overall, especially if you can restrict to a narrow alphabet.

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks for the benchmark. And you've got my respect for that comment. Rather seldom that someone posts that sort of comment. Guess it really depends on the input for this one. I'll edit the answer.